# Composition with compact operator implies uniform convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach Space and $Y$ be a normed linear space. Let $(A_n)$ and $A$ be bounded linear operators from $X\rightarrow Y$ such that $\Vert (A_n-A)x \Vert\rightarrow0$ for every $x\in X$. If $K:X\rightarrow X$ is compact, then show $\Vert (A_n-A)K \Vert \rightarrow 0$.

I'm not sure how to proceed in this question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $K$ is compact, $A_nK$ and $AK$ are also compact.

Comment: @Aweygan How can I use that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the claim is not true. Then there is $\delta>0$ and $x_n$ with $\|x_n\|_X=1$ such that
$$
\|(A_n-A)Kx_n\| \ge\delta
$$
for infinitely many $n$. Now $(x_n)$ is bounded, so $(Kx_n)$ contains 
a converging subsequence $Kx_n \to y$.
So
$$
\|(A-A_n)Kx_n \|\le \|(A-A_n)Ky\| +\|(A-A_n)(Kx_n-y) \|\\
\le \|(A-A_n)Ky\| +\|A-A_n\|\cdot\|Kx_n-y \|.
$$
Now the first claim goes to zero by assumption, the second goes to zero as $(A_n)$ is bounded (uniform boundedness principle).

[The answer is a little bit sloppy - one has choose subsequencess all the time. I hope you get the idea anyway.]

Comment: In the first term, shouldn't it be just $y$ instead of $Kx_n$?

Comment: @SahibaArora No, but there is an error.  The first line should read $$\|(A-A_n)Kx_n \|\le \|(A-A_n)y\| +\|(A-A_n)(Kx_n-y) \|.$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @SahibaArora corrected. thanks for pointing out